# Spring/Hibernate persisting entity with nested entity (by nested entity id / primary key only)

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

Using Spring 4.1.7 and Hibernate 4.3.10.

I am trying to create a new custom `Note` object via a form POST to a Spring Controller. The Note object contains a `Book` object, and both `Note` and `Book` are persisted using using Hibernate.

The Controller class that the form POSTs to:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/notes")
public class NoteRestController {

    [...]

    @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView createForView(final Model model,
            @ModelAttribute final Note note) {

        /*-- DEBUG. works, but probably not ideal.
        {
            final Book validBook = daoService.retrieveBook(note.getBook()
                    .getId());
            note.setBook(validBook);
        }//*/

        UUID createdNoteId = daoService.createNote(note);

        model.addAttribute("note",
                daoService.retrieveNote(createdNoteId));

        return new ModelAndView("note/note");
    }
}
```

The `Note` object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "note")
public class Note {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Type(type = "pg-uuid")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "book", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Book book;

    [...]
}
```

The `Book` object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Type(type = "pg-uuid")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    [...]
}
```

The underlying database (currently Postgres 9.1) defines that the `Book.name` column is NOT NULL.

What I want to do is use Spring forms to create a new `Note` by just passing in the unique `id` of the `Book` (and note title as String).

My test HTML form (page formatting removed for brevity):

```
<form:form method="post" id="create" action="/notes/create" 
    commandName="note">
    <form:input type="text" id="title" name="title" path="title" />
    <form:input type="text" id="book.id" name="book.id" path="book.id" value="" />

    <input value="Create" type="submit" name="Create">
</form:form>
```

When I submit the form (with a valid value in `book.id`), The Controller creates a `Book` instance in the `Note` with the `id` set, but with a null `name` field. Understandable, since I don't pass it in, but nor do I want to pass it in every time.

When I submit the form with the DEBUG block commented out, an exception is thrown regarding the null `name` field. However, if I uncomment the debug block (which prefetches the `Book` and sets it into `Note` instance) everything works.

Is there a better way that I can do this without manually fetching nested objects? Ultimately, I intend to have more entities within `Note` and I don't want to have to fetch them all before creating `Note`.

I hope this makes sense!

Comment: Think about it conceptually . `Note` has got a must relationship with book. It MUST have book before you could persist it according to this design (which does seem correct design). The `Note` object passed to `createForView` should have book already. Meaning caller does need to handle this integrity.